# How do I set a github branch protection rule based on the success or failure of an entire github actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set a github branch protection rule based on the success or failure of a github actions workflow.

You can see the workflow here:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml

The workflow passes, and I even have a working badge for it, but I am unable to set a branch protection rule requiring that it pass as a status check.

I *can* set a branch protection rule based on any one of the individual builds in the matrix, but I don't want to set all of them individually and keep track of that as my matrix rule changes.

As you can see from the screenshots, I am unable to pick "build", the name of the job (although I can pick any of the sub-builds), and I am also unable to pick "tests", the name of the workflow as a whole (it does not change if I use an uppercase t).

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Screenshot one: I can pick a sub-build but not the entire build job.

[image: I can pick a sub-build but not the entire build job]

Screenshot two: I can't pick the name of the overall "Tests" workflow at all.

[image: I can't pick the name of the overall "Tests" workflow at all]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a trick to add one step to the workflow to collect all jobs from the matrix to one check:

```yaml
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: All tests ok
        if: ${{ !(contains(needs.*.result, 'failure')) }}
        run: exit 0
      - name: Some tests failed
        if: ${{ contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') }}
        run: exit 1
```

`if: always()` is obligatory to collect failed tasks, otherwise PR will never get a proper status check. Also, this is an additional step for you to pay (if you use paid plans).

Comment: Would this also work if the build job was canceled? Or a single job inside build?

Comment: @Max yes, the `always()` condition guarantees it will be run even if it is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have a single job with a matrix.  That means you'll end with 9 possibilities (3 node options × 3 MongoDB options).  Each of those is considered a separate status check and can be enabled or disabled as mandatory individually.  This is so that you can add new options without making them mandatory up front.

If you want every one of those jobs to pass, then you need to choose every one of the 9 jobs and mark them as required.

Comment: So it is not possible to do a status check simply on “everything worked?”

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to just require every status check to pass.

Comment: OK thank you, full points, not your fault it's not the answer I wanted to hear (:

Comment: @bk2204 is it possible to add another job that depends on the job with the matrix, and then check it? It'd be a dummy job, would do practically nothing, but it would mark the fact that the job with the matrix finished successfully

Comment: I don't know, honestly.  You could try it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @stachel doesn't work when the matrix is empty. In this case, github sadly returns `result: failure`. The empty matrix can happen when you dynamically generate test cases, but no cases match

To solve this, you have to add on an extra output to detect "failed because there are no jobs" vs. "the matrix job failed"

If you have a `test` matrix, then add a custom `did_run` output to it:

e.g.

```yaml
test:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    needs:
      - detect-packages
    outputs:
      did_run: ${{ steps.did_run.outputs.did_run }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        packages: ${{ fromJson(needs.detect-packages.outputs.packages) }}
    steps:
      - name: Setting Did Run flag to true
        id: did_run
        if: always()
        run: echo "did_run=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

The key thing is to add `did_run` to the outputs section, and the corresponding step to set the output

And then finally, you can generate the rollup result using jq to parse the `needs.test` output

```yaml
test-rollup:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    needs: test
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: Ensure tests succeeded
        run: echo '${{ toJson(needs.test) }}' | jq '.result == "success" or (.result == "failure" and .outputs.did_run == null)'
```

## Debugging output

Since it's not fun to repeatedly run github actions to see what output is returned, here's the output of `needs.test` in the following scenarios

### Matrix has tests, all tests run successfully

```json
{
    "result": "success",
    "outputs": {
        "did_run": "true"
    }
}
```

### Matrix has tests, but at least one of the tests fails

```json
{
    "result": "failure",
    "outputs": {
        "did_run": "true"
    }
}
```

### Matrix does not have any tests

```json
{
    "result": "failure",
    "outputs": {}
}
```