# GitHub Actions are pending despite their matrix jobs are finished

Tags: github, github-actions

Inside GitHub workflow there were 2 jobs - unit and e2e tests. Recently we changed them to use `matrix` strategy (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) in order parallelise them. All parallelised jobs are successful, e.g.

[image]

However 2 jobs are always "pending" despite their successful parallelised jobs -

[image]

How to get rid of them? Should we create completely new workflow to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked your branch protection rules? When you rename a workflow, I do not think the **Require branches to be up to date before merging** option updates automatically if you have configured it previously.

Comment: Pretty sure this is indeed because the status is required in branch protection, and the protection rule wasn't updated.

Comment: you are right, it's branch protection rules. But what if I want to keep these jobs required? Do you think i need to add all these matrix jobs to make all of them required now? e.g. unit tests (chunk 1), unit tests (chunk 2), etc. wdyt?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250293/17889834) help? 
Adding another job that checks the output of your tests and set the branch protection on that. If any of the jobs in the matrix fails, the "checking job" will fail.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good way to solve it!